# ios custom delegate is null after second click in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlcache

I have a custom `UIWebView` (EpubWebView), with a custom `NSURLCache` (EpubCache) for handling requests.
i created a custom delegate for handling request.

`EpubCache.h`

```
@protocol EpubCacheDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)hadleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request; 
@end

@interface EpubCache : NSURLCache 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <EpubCacheDelegate> cacheDelegate; 
@end
```

`EpubCache.m`

```
import "EpubCache.h"
@interface EpubCache ()
@end

@implementation EpubCache
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return [self.cacheDelegate hadleRequest:request];
}
@end
```

`EpubWebView .h`

```
@interface EpubWebView : UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate, EpubCacheDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) EpubCache *mLocalCache;
@end
```

`EpubWebView.m`

```
- (void) localInit
{    
    self.mLocalCache = [[EpubCache alloc] init];
    self.mLocalCache.cacheDelegate = self;
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:self.mLocalCache];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)hadleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    // return handled request
}
```

on the other hand i have a `navigationcontroller` with a `tableview` and the destination view controller have this webview.

when i ran the app and click on an item in `tableview`, everything is fine and `delegate` works as expected.

if i click back and click on other item in tableview, things goes **wrong**, the `cachedResponseForRequest` getting **called** but the `hadleRequest` **wont**, i checked and findout that the `delegate` is **null**!

i can not figure out what is happening here.

any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

`EpubWebView.m`

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self localInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        [self localInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
        [self localInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

the segue of the tableview that bring up the view controller that contain `EpubWebView`

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
    BookViewController *bookController = segue.destinationViewController;

    bookController.mBook = booksList[indexPath.row];
}
```

and `BookViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mWebView = [[EpubWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mainView.frame];
    [self.mainView addSubView:mWebView];
    [mWebView setBook:self.mBook];

}
```

Comment: is "`localInit`" being called each time you click on the table view?  Also, could you change the name of the "`hadleRequest`" to "`handleRequest`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes, `localInit` called in `init` each time, please look at the updated question. `hadleRequest` has a typo but it does not affect the code.

Comment: EPubCache is alloc'd & init'd each time EPubWebView is alloc'd and init'd.  So I am thinking EPubCache gets released & dealloc'd as often as your EPubWebView objects do as well.  How about creating EPubCache *once* and then passing it in (or setting the property) from whatever view controller that calls EPubWebView?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, you mean something like this? `static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ { 
    self.mLocalCache = [[EpubCache alloc] init];
}); self.mLocalCache.cacheDelegate = self;
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:self.mLocalCache];` ,

Comment: close but not exactly; show the code that brings up your EPubWebView from the table.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann , please see update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few modifications.  First, remove your "`localInit`" method, then create a new function in EPubWebView:

```
- (void) setCache: (EpubCache *)localCache 
{
    localCache.cacheDelegate = self;
}
```

Now, you can create and hold onto your cache in your BookViewController via these lines in the .m file:

```
@interface BookViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) EpubCache *mLocalCache;

@end
```

and change your BookViewController's viewDidLoad method to look like:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    self.mLocalCache = [[EpubCache alloc] init];

    // only need to do this once, at viewDidLoad time
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:self.mLocalCache ];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    mWebView = [[EpubWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mainView.frame];
    [mWebView setCache:self.mLocalCache];
    [self.mainView addSubView:mWebView];
    [mWebView setBook:self.mBook];
}
```

Comment: tnx alot, with a little modification your code works perfectly, but i'm not sure what is wrong with my previous code, could you explain it a little?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in my comment up there, 
EPubCache is alloc'd & init'd each time EpubWebView is alloc'd and init'd. So I am thinking EPubCache gets released & dealloc'd as often as your EpubWebView objects do as well. What you're doing now is creating EpubCache once and retaining it in memory and each time you display a EpubWebView, it's referring to the same cache object in memory (which won't get released by ARC).  Makes sense?